# Recursive code eating up whole memory

Tags: windows, memory-management, recursion, stack, com+

I have a C++ project which has a extremely recursive function. This project when deployed and run on the dedicated machine it is eating upto 12 GB of memory. Previously, this process used to fail at 2GB limit. Hence, I converted this entire solution having 20 projects to 64 bit platform on visual studio 2010 platform. Now, it doesn't stop at 2 GB but eating up almost my whole RAM. Total RAM usage is 15.9 GB out of total 16 GB. I am using COM+ to run these application as dllhost. My questions are:

1. How to limit the memory being allocated fully causing failure of the process?
2. Does windows frees the memory after recursion is over? Because I am not seeing this process releasing memory until I kill this process.
3. Terminating case is not the problem, I guess, beacuse my job is succeeded by using Expiration Time option in Recycling in Component Services.Or is there any other problem?

Comment: In order to solve the problem, you will first need to understand the problem. At the moment you don't have any understanding of what is going wrong. You need to understand why and how your system is eating memory. Until you can do that you will make no progress.

Comment: is there any way I can know the allocated memory is for stack during recursion or for any other purpose? Actually I am just given this problem to be solved.I am completely new to this problem.

Comment: Typical stacks on Windows are 1MB in size. If you are eating 16GB of memory, that's not memory on the stack. Of course it could be heap memory due to deep recursion. Or your app could just leak. Or there could be countless other explanations. There's no evidence here that the issue is due to recursion. You've asked the question way to early in your debugging process. First step is to understand the problem. That's your next task. We cannot help you do that.